# create a django user while creating a records for model

Tags: python, django, django-models

`models.py` as below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class members(models.Model):

    auto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_name = models.OneToOneField(User)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='webapi', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
    wife_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
    number_of_child = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, default='')
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('member_name',)
```

Now The above has been linked with django auth Users table and in steriliser it shows the existing Django users and I have to choose one during the submit.

But my requirement is as a admin user I login and then provide the member_name manually which should automatically create a django user also

Answer (score 0):

[django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#readme) has a feature for this, specifically [AutoOneToOneField](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#autoonetoonefield).

Sample from their github:

```
from annoying.fields import AutoOneToOneField

class MyProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

This should automatically create a User.

Comment: still in django REST "serializers" (i.e) in the UI it is showing a dropdown with only one user i.e the super user which I have created. Now each time when I enter the user name automatically the djanto user should be created

Comment: I'm not really familiar with django rest, but this shouldn't make a big difference. You'll need to override the field that is shown to you in the admin page while you are creating a new member. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) explains this better than I could.